# Highlight Text in TextView or WebView

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to Highlight text in a `TextView` or `WebView`?

I see it is possible in a `EditText`

[Highligh text in a EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/android-is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

I'd like to do the same in `TextView` or `WebView`.
Thats Possible?

Comment: Check this out as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309093/how-to-allow-the-user-to-select-a-text-range-in-a-textview-similar-to-edittext

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Comment: What's the way to do it in a webview?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

enable TextView's Spannable storage!
by default Spannable storage in EditText is true.

so

```
TextView myTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String  textString = "StackOverFlow Rocks!!!"; 
Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString);
spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 14, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
myTV.setText(spanText);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's work fine. But I think create Spannable Text by: Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString); is better than textView.setText() and textView.getText().

Comment: Is there any way to create a justified text-view and then set multiple spans to it?

Comment: Is there a way to display the highlighted matches in a webview?

Comment: Great answer that helped me but two things strike me about the Android API related to this: 1) this is still the best way to do this after 9 years?  Seems like there would be a better/cleaner API call. 2) It is very odd that you have to set the actual text value of the view item to set the style.  This feels like a Conflict of Concerns (versus Separation of Concerns). Feels like style and content mixed together.

Answer (score 1):

As well you could use this one solution for `WebView`. Call `findAllAsync`

```
webview.findAllAsync(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit)).getText().toString());
```

than add `FindListener` to `WebView`

```
    webview.setFindListener(new FindListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal, int numberOfMatches, boolean isDoneCounting) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Matches: " + numberOfMatches, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Iterate in result with `webview.findNext(false);` where false/true shows the direction.

But this solution was added in `API level 16`!!! Instead of you can setup JavaScript for higlihting - http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm

Answer (score 0):

For `TextView`

You can use `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true)` in your activity or fragment or adapter.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you do not have to develop this feature by yourself. You just need to use EditText instead TextView, while you set the android:editable of EditText to false.

My answer is here, hope it may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026292/966405