# How to allow the user to select a text range in a TextView (Similar to EditText)

Tags: android, textview

I've got a `TextView` that I would like to allow the user to select a range of text from within it. The `TextView` takes up the entire width and height of the device (minus some padding and a title at the top). In an `EditText` if you long-click you get a selection overlay that allows you to set your selection left and right bounds. I'd like this functionality in a `TextView`. I've read that in API level 9 (2.3) (http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html) there are new text selection controls, but I'm having difficulty implementing this. I'm doing this right now:

```
eic = new InputConnection( bookTextView );
eic.beginBatchEdit();
```

But it doesn't do anything noticable. Does anyone know how to use `InputConnection` correctly? Thanks.

**Edit:** I don't necessarily need to use what I was attempting above. I ultimately want to use either a `TextView` or an `EditText` which looks and feels like a `TextView` and be able to select text using a dragging cursor. Then I would like to manipulate the selected text with various context menu options (or a menu that pops up above the selected text).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an idea.. Add an EditText with a TextView background, Here is an example

```
<EditText 
android:text=" This is not an editable EditText" 
android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
android:editable = "false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background = "@android:drawable/dark_header">
</EditText>
```

add this to your xml in the place of TextView

Comment: editable is deprecated, you can use `android:inputType="none"`

Comment: `inputType="none"` does not prevent the text from being changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable the `TextView`'s [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) storage. See [Highlight Text in TextView or WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview) for an example.

**See also:**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html

Comment: I know how to use Spans and use highlights, but what I'm after is the EditText's "look and feel" when selecting text (with anchors on either side).

Answer (score 0):

You could display the text in a WebView and enable text selection. If you want to only use a textview/edittext, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview/2120190#2120190) is an answer that might help you and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) is information on the Spannable class that might help you accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not have to develop this feature by yourself. You just need to use EditText instead TextView, while you set the android:editable of EditText to false. My idea is the same as sandy's.

My code is here, hope it may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026292/966405

Answer (score 0):

After long internet surfing to find a solution, i prefered create my own class

https://github.com/orionsource/SelectableTextViewer

[image]

**Goal features:**

1. Easy to use - only one class
2. Support for text and Html.fromHtml
3. Can be in ScrollView with correct touches
4. Cursors can be redefined
5. Color of selection can be redefined

Comment: @ Dmitry Nelepov . Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions either too long or not working for me.

What you need is to add just `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true)`
in your `activity` or `fragment` or `adapter`.