# Select text from textview on one click in android

Tags: android, select, text, textview

In one touch i want to get a option to select and copy the text from textview like the image show here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [onClickListener for the TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328757/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text):

```
ClipboardManager clipboard =
    (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
clipboard.setText(yourTextView.getText());
```

`ed` : Answer to the question in comments :

```
  yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: add your code here

        }
    });
```

Comment: but how to get  a portion of text from that textview

Comment: You have to make your TextView Spannable, refer [to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview) or better [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309093/how-to-allow-the-user-to-select-a-text-range-in-a-textview-similar-to-edittext/7035836#7035836)

Comment: hi Reno thanks for your  suggestion  ..but how to give onclick option to textview dynamically?

Comment: i created that  textview through java code..so how to give on click option for that textview .

Answer (score 2):

Just Set "textIsSelectable" on the TextView to true

```
    <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Detail Text"
                android:id="@+id/txtBody"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

just add this to your `TextView` xml file :

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```