# Android - Text Selectable - select part of a text

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

How can I make a TextView selectable in API <= 11 ? I search a lot and found that i could use Editext as a TextView, but this away don't looks good anyway, and I need to send the part selected of a text to a new Activity, Someone could help me with this ?

A example of what i'm searching for is the Onlongclick pressed in app OperaMini.
After a long click he opens a cursor for the user select that part of the text that him Need and a ContextMenu for that selected part.

Thank's.

[image]

I need to make something like this Print, when longclinck, make appears the selectors of text(the blue tips on the print) and show the part selected.

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832466/select-text-from-textview-on-one-click-in-android

Answer (score 14):

You either in **xml** make it selectable

```
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

or making your textview clickable by assigning it a Onclicklistener

```
  TextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        clipboard.setText(TextView.getText());
        }
    });
```

Comment: please accept the answer ( the tick ) if it helped you. and welcome to stackOverFlow

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed-Ekri, but doesn't work. I try the two forms that you say but nothing happen in my TextView.

Comment: Someone could help me ? Please

Comment: It works but not in all apis' .. so use this library to get a working clipboard in all apis' https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/ClipIP .. please accept and rate the question if it helps

Comment: it works to copy. Thanks a lot. I have now just a dubt. How  Can i get a range of text to send for clipboardManager ?

Comment: Ok, but... How Can I display the cursor to the user select the range of text like the print?
Thank you, really @AhmedEkri.