# Android How to select text from TextView for a book reader?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, ebook-reader

I would like to create a book reader and for this i have a problem of selecting some text and i don't know what is the best way. I read some posts in which they where using EditText for selection. But this is not so usefull because when you long tap it shows select word/select all and the keyboard appears, what i want is only the possibility to select text, listen the selection and then using Spannable/Linkify to edit that portion of text.

If there is no easy thing to use the standard text cursor controllers, can i create a custom cursor controllers or something like that ?

I read this posts:

[Select text from TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991201/select-text-from-textview)

[How to allow the user to select a text range in a TextView (Similar to EditText)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309093/how-to-allow-the-user-to-select-a-text-range-in-a-textview-similar-to-edittext)

Thank you in advance.

Update:

I found this class android.text.Selection that seems to use the cursor controllers But i don't find any examples on google about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`android:textIsSelectable="true"`](http://goo.gl/Dfpyf) on your `TextView`.

Comment: 10x, but this is for API 11+. I would like a solution from API 10+.

Comment: @djcharon: Ah, then I suspect you're stuck with the workarounds outlined in those other SO questions.

Comment: I see, do you know how to create a selector ?

Comment: @djcharon: A selector refers to a `StateListDrawable`: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: I just found out that the "selectors" that i want are called cursor controllers.

Comment: @djcharon: Yeah, I don't know what that means, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm made a custom TextView with selection capability by studying Android's source code.
Please see my answer from the other question [Android- How can I show text selection on textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346604/android-how-can-i-show-text-selection-on-textview/17137052#17137052)