# Android- How can I show text selection on textview?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, textselection

I am implementing a epub reading app where I am using textview for showing text of epub. I want to select text from textview when user long presses on textview and then do multiple operations on selected text of textview like highlight etc.. 
So, How can I show those cursors to user to select text whatever user wants.

*I dont want to use EditText and make it look like textview. May be overriding textview is prefered.

*I have attached screenshot to explain what I am looking for-

[image: Screenshot from moon+reader to show text selection in it which I want in my app]

Comment: sorry the image does not loaded successfully...try it again

Comment: I can see the image at my side :\.. i ll reupload it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is asked long time ago, when I had this problem myself as well. I made a Selectable TextView myself for my own app Jade Reader. I've hosted the solution to GitHub. (The code at BitBucket ties to the application, but it's more complete and polished.)

[Selectable TextView (on GitHub)](https://github.com/zhouray/SelectableTextView)

[Jade Reader (on BitBucket)](https://bitbucket.org/rayzhou/jaderead-restart/overview)

[image: selection]

Using the following code will make your TextView selectable.

```
package com.zyz.mobile.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SelectableTextView mTextView;
    private int mTouchX;
    private int mTouchY;
    private final static int DEFAULT_SELECTION_LEN = 5;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // make sure the TextView's BufferType is Spannable, see the main.xml
        mTextView = (SelectableTextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text);
        mTextView.setDefaultSelectionColor(0x40FF00FF);


        mTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                showSelectionCursors(mTouchX, mTouchY);
                return true;
            }
        });
        mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTextView.hideCursor();
            }
        });
        mTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mTouchX = (int) event.getX();
                mTouchY = (int) event.getY();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void showSelectionCursors(int x, int y) {
        int start = mTextView.getPreciseOffset(x, y);

        if (start > -1) {
            int end = start + DEFAULT_SELECTION_LEN;
            if (end >= mTextView.getText().length()) {
                end = mTextView.getText().length() - 1;
            }
            mTextView.showSelectionControls(start, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dear Ray Zhou, i have problem while facing JTextView inside scrollView  that have paddingTop attribute, i think you need to add padding offset in  getScrollXInternal() in JTextView. correct me if i'am wrong, thanks

Comment: Hi, @dreamfighter I have made a couple of fix to the JTextView since I posted this, but the fixes are in BitBucket, not GitHub. You could take a look there.

Comment: It just work inside scrollView :( . how can i change it to work inside layout?

Comment: @RayZhou Do you still have a public repo for Jade Reader? The BitBucket one seems to have bit the bucket.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the minimum Android version that you'd like to support.

On 3.0+, you have the [textIsSelectable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textIsSelectable) attribute on the TextView, which enables this behavior. E.g.:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:bufferType="spannable"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="28dip"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Below that, you best bet is to use an EditText that looks and behaves like a TextView (apart from the slection thing). Or you can implement this feature yourself using spans.

Comment: But if u see screenshot i posted which is of moon+ reader.. and they have that feature.. So what u think ? do they are using edittext for that ?

Comment: My bet is that they used EditText for that. Try using HierarchyViewer, it may reveal this. Or try asking the devs :)

Comment: This is obviously the way to go.