# Select data from textview

Tags: android

How can I get selected data from textview, when range is provided.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything in particular?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346604/android-how-can-i-show-text-selection-on-textview

Comment: To confirm: have you already selected the text, as above (and using android:textIsSelectable), and now you want to know what to do with it?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks yes I have already tried some methods ....

Comment: @RichardHorrocks .... Yes, my textview is selectable (in activities xml)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks ..... now I want to get the selected data from the text view .....

Comment: @SarwarErfan .... not working ....

Comment: You might be able to use the ClipboardManager, as per one of the answers in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025818/select-copy-text-in-a-textview

Answer (score 0):

Following up on one of my comments...

One of the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025818/select-copy-text-in-a-textview) suggests that the [ClipboardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) may be the way to solve this.