# Prevent app crash when cut operation in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I put text-selectable TextView in Android layout with `setTextIsSelectable(true)` and the text is set by `Html.fromHtml(sometexts)`.
It works good to allow user to copy text.
My JellyBean device gives small baloons with cut/copy/paste buttons on top of the selected text.

But when user accidently click **cut** icon left side of the **copy** menu, it crashes.

The log is given as below but there is no point to handle this exception in my application.
How to prevent app crash?

```
01-06 19:29:16.025    2048-2048/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to android.text.Editable
        at android.widget.TextView.deleteText_internal(TextView.java:8865)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTextContextMenuItem(TextView.java:8315)
        at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.onClick(Editor.java:3556)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4114)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17097)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4885)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure and I can't test it right now but maybe try to put that in your TextView xml :

```
android:bufferType="spannable"
```

If it's still not working you can implement yourself your action for the selectable event.
Look at the answer of this question here :
[Android- How can I show text selection on textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346604/android-how-can-i-show-text-selection-on-textview)

Comment: `android:bufferType="spannable"` does NOT solve the problem but your provided link gives me help a lot.