# How to get the Share and Find Options when select the textview in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-textattributes

> I am using the following tag in textview to copy the text.

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

> And I am getting the following Screen when i am selecting the textview.

[image]

> But,how to get the Find and Share options like below screen.

[image]

Comment: what's the functionality of find option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After lot of research i found the answer for my question. Answer is [Android- How can I show text selection on textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346604/android-how-can-i-show-text-selection-on-textview)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it by yourself:

When the tap/long press on the text, display your popup.

I would probably do it, using `OnLongClickListener()` on the text:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)

Comment: Is it possible to select the user wanted area @Thomas

Comment: If `textIsSelectable` is set to `true`, user will have the ability to select their area and copy it but you won't be able to provide the share feature.

If you use `OnLongClickListener()`, you can display your own popup but the user won't be able to select a specific area.

That's a compromise.

You can probably implement your own TextView behavior to provide both, but it's not gonna be easy.

Comment: how to select the specific textarea @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a custom dialog as your own.

All procedure is below.

Crate a Custom Dialog Class:

```
public class CustomizedDialog extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

Context context;

public CustomizedDialog(Context context) {

    super(context);

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Button aButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDialogCancel);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    // TextView objMesaageView = new TextView(context);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {

    super.setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

}
Then call this class from your activity.

```
CustomizedDialog dialog;
    // open a dialog
private void showDialog() {
    dialog = new CustomizedDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_number_type);
    dialog.setTitle("Add Black List Number");

       TextView textViewAddNumber=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutCallLog);

   textViewAddNumber.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // write your code here.

    }
});


    dialog.show();
}
```

My layout xml like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:background="#9acd32" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutAddBlockNumbers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutCallLog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="test" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAddNumber"
            style="@style/heading_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:text="@string/add_from_call_log" />
    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```