# make Android Textview or EditText selectable

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, selectable

I want to make `EditText` or `Textview` selectable in my android project .
project is for android 4.0+ . I add this : `txtView.setTextIsSelectable(true)` and also : `txtView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new myCallback());`
to make my custom selection menu .
but this error happend when i want to select the text .

```
W/TextView﹕ TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.
```

i searched about the error but didn't find the solution .what should i do ?

Comment: Check if you have android:focusable="false" or android:focusableInTouchMode="false" in your xml

Comment: Have a look at this:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346604/android-how-can-i-show-text-selection-on-textview)

Comment: What do you really want to do..select the edittext and textview text or showing a color when this widgets are selected.

Comment: @Surenderkumar i want to make it possible for users to share the text they selected in textview .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:text="" />
```

*API Level 11 and up only

Comment: Putting `textIsSelectable` on my `EditText` breaks the EditText focus, in particular when you close the keyboard (you can never open it up again).

Comment: any solution can u offer @dextor ,so that I can edit my answer,

Comment: It seems like this is only related to `EditText`. So no need to change your answer.

Comment: Does it really work? I tried the same. But, it's not working. Getting the following warning log while trying to select text

**W/TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.**

Comment: Without textIsSelectable Android is not logging "Textview does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.". Also this doesn't solve the issue. How was this exactly helpful?

Answer (score 0):

setTextIsSelectable does fix the problem on Android 7.1.1 for sure. The setEnabled(false) and then true didn't work.

```
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

My exact situation was having setFocusable(false) and adding an onClickListener, then setting setFocusable(true) and onClickListener(null) gave me the error in the OP.

(not correct syntax but you get the idea)