# android:textIsSelectable="true" for TextView inside Listview does not work

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have the problem with TextView inside ListView below.

In listview, I have a TextView and I have set

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

But, when I long click on TextView, I see log print

```
TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.
```

So I can not use Copy and Paste function for TextView.

If you have any idea to resolve this issue, please give some hint to fix it.

Thanks so much

Comment: check it ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605680/make-android-textview-or-edittext-selectable

Comment: please check you minimum SDK level in manifest, it should be 11 or above.

Comment: JigneshAnsodariya : My minSdkVersion is 14

@nandkishormewara : I set android:focusable="false" or android:focusableInTouchMode="false" in my xml. But It does not work.

Note : It only happen for TextView inside ListView

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Answer (score 0):

Just try this...

```
  ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourList);    
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public void onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,long id) {
                    TextView yourFirstTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.yourFirstTextViewId);                    
                    copyTextToClipboard(yourFirstTextView);                   

    public void copyTextToClipboard(TextView txtView){
         int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
         if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
             android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
             clipboard.setText(txtView.getText().toString());
         } else {
             android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
             android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("text label",txtView.getText().toString());
             clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
         }
    }
```

May it work.

Comment: Thanks @SJ143 : I don't want to copy all text, I only the part of text by select text

Comment: In list.setOnItemLongClickListener, try to add textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);  and remove it from xml and instead use:

android:inputType="textMultiLine"

Comment: Hi @SJ143 : I still don't resolve this issue yet. I'm being continue search google :D

Answer (score 0):

TextView sets the width to "match_parent" `android:layout_width="match_parent"`