# Creating custom Text Selection actions

Tags: android

I want to do long press and select some text, I can see it in many apps, but I have no ideas for this. I am looking for some ideas or some examples?
the following picture is my goal.

[image: What I want]

Comment: I don't think its possible, as long pressing the text will open the default android context menu and we cannot change that. However you can change it in a custom rom.

Comment: @Shank I don't think that Adobe or any E-book reader is requiring a custom ROM. Don't you think?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin yes you are right, i never noticed them having it

Comment: for TextView I only need android:textIsSelectable="true", But I don't want to do it on TextView, I want to do on SurfaceView, so I need to know the details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about what you are looking for.

- If you're just willing to make your `textView` **selectable**, make sure it looks like this:

  ```
   <TextView
   ...
   android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
  ```

  Which is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025818/select-copy-text-in-a-textview).
- But if what you are looking for is a **Custom Text Selection Action**, fortunately for you, [Ian Lake](https://medium.com/@ianhlake?source=footer_card) has [A GREAT TUTORIAL](https://medium.com/google-developers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999#.artde1w1p) about doing just that.

  If you're into libraries, you can check [this one](https://github.com/zhouray/SelectableTextView) on *Github*.

  You might be looking as well for some related questions. If so, check this [one here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346604/android-how-can-i-show-text-selection-on-textview).

Comment: thank you for you help, I will look at you answer links. actually I want do it on SurfaceView, but I only want to know the UI design.

Comment: For TextView, I have found some ideas. Now I do it on SurfaceView. so I can't use Spannable to set the selected texts, I use popupWindow to do this, But PopupWindow is expensive. can you give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file and under the desired `TextView`, add the following attribute:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I want to do this on SurfaceView, so I want to the details.

Comment: I have found some ideas from AnixPasBesoin's answer, thank you!