# Copy text from edittext in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select + copy text in a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025818/select-copy-text-in-a-textview)

1. Can I prevent the user from editing the text in the edittext  box?
2. Also is it possible copy text from an edittext box in Android without the softkeyboard showing?

Basically I want a text file (e.g. a story) displayed on an Android with the user having the opportunity to copy and paste. I don't want user to be able to edit the text nor do I want to keyboard to show while copying and pasting.

Thanks

Comment: Similar question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025818/select-copy-text-in-a-textview

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is that you can use a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) instead of a EditText to display the text. Then you can put a copy icon or button near the text and programmatically copy the text using the guide here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

See this thread as well:

[Copy text from TextView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952914/copy-text-from-textview-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

For Prevent Editing of Text just put `android:editable="false"` inside your **EditText** attributes in the xml file.

And for allowing Copy & Paste, just put `android:textIsSelectable="true"` inside the same.

I hope you get what you want.