# HTML textarea onselect doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I have a function that I run when the user selects a word in the textarea (typically by double clicking it). It works great on the PC. On android devices, long clicking a word selects it, but doesn't fire onselect.

Is there any way to fix it? Or perhaps some work around to select a word on normal click?

Here's the line in the cshtml

```
<textarea class="all_txt" id="all_txt" onselect="wordSelected(this, @loggedIn)"></textarea>
```

And here's the javascript function

```
function wordSelected(txt, loggedIn) {
    var selected = txt.value.substring(txt.selectionStart, txt.selectionEnd);
    var substring = selected.trim();
    start = selected.search(substring) + txt.selectionStart;
    end = start + substring.length;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952914/copy-text-from-textview-on-android).

Comment: What have you tried? I haven't had similar issue but first thing id try would be prevent default at start of your JS function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault..

Comment: Uma, this is completely unrelated the my question

Comment: Shark, the function doesn't even run, where would I prevent default?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up adding a button that calls `wordSelected` which the user can click after he selected the word. Not optimal, but seems to be the only way.