# How to highlight characters in String for Textview?

Tags: android, string, textview

String = " This is SAMPLE"

I want to increase the size of the SAMPLE alone in String to highlight, but need to be in a single string, this is to set in TextView.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is <font color='#707070' size='20'>
            SAMPLE</font>"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
String str = "This is <b>SAMPLE</b>";
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Moreover, you may decorate your string (str) with html tags to alter the looks.

Or to highlight a part of text without using html stuff, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Html.fromHtml()` in `setText()` of `TextView`. Supported Html Tags can be found here [Html Tags Supported by TextView](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible if you pass the text as html with your highlighted part enclosed in html `<bold>` tag.

Comment: Shubhayu - yes you are right, its just make difference. If you use font size tag you can highlight at your wishing size.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1, Format your string in HTML and use HTML.from("Your text");

2, Use spannable. A complete guide can find  [link here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177)