# Highlight a specific text in WebView android 4.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-webview

I want to highlight a specific (searching) text on WebView. I use the code

```
 myWebView.findAll(txtSearch);

 try {
      for (Method m : WebView.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
         if (m.getName().equals("setFindIsUp")) {
          m.setAccessible(true);
          m.invoke(myWebView, true);
          break;
        }
    }
     } catch (Exception ignored) {
       }
```

This works great on Android 2.2, but it doesn't work on Android 4.0 and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, highlight text on WebView works great on Android 2.2, but he appeared as not working on Android 4.0 and above

look at this link

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview)

Answer (score 1):

> i am also trying this highlight of text ,it is working perfectly on
>   android version 2.2 but if i am trying the same thing in another
>   version than the highlight text is not shown and one more thing that
>   findasync() only works for api 16 .May be using java script can help i
>   am working on that if it works i'll tell to you.
>
> thanks