# Highlight text view in android

Tags: android, textview

I want to highlight textview in android same this image
[image]

How i do that? Thanks

Like as this link  http://youtube.com/watch?v=0qE3egNettY

Comment: Try refering this question ,this should answer you question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview

Answer (score 4):

this is what you want:

```
package org.pskink.shape;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.PictureDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DrawableSpanTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawable_span_test);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Spannable text = new SpannableStringBuilder("This is liric of the song");
        setSpans(tv, text);
        tv.setText(text);
    }

    private void setSpans(TextView tv, Spannable text) {
        int blueColor = 0xff0000ff;
        int redColor = 0xffff0000;
        ForegroundColorSpan blue = new ForegroundColorSpan(blueColor);
        ForegroundColorSpan red = new ForegroundColorSpan(redColor);
        HalfColorSpan o = new HalfColorSpan("o", tv, blueColor, redColor);
        text.setSpan(blue, 0, 14, 0);
        text.setSpan(o, 14, 15, 0);
        text.setSpan(red, 15, text.length(), 0);
    }

    class HalfColorSpan extends DynamicDrawableSpan {
        private final static String TAG = "DrawableSpanTest.HalfColorSpan";
        Picture mPicture;
        public HalfColorSpan(String text, TextView tv, int c0, int c1) {
            super(ALIGN_BASELINE);
            mPicture = new Picture();
            TextPaint p = tv.getPaint();
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
            float width = p.measureText(text);
            float height = bounds.height();
            float y = height;
            Canvas c = mPicture.beginRecording((int) width, (int) height);
            c.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);
//          c.drawColor(0x22000000);
            p = new TextPaint(p);
            p.setColor(c0);
            c.clipRect(0, 0, width / 2, height, Region.Op.REPLACE);
            c.drawText(text, 0, y, p);
            p.setColor(c1);
            c.clipRect(width / 2, 0, width, height, Region.Op.REPLACE);
            c.drawText(text, 0, y, p);
            c.restore();
            mPicture.endRecording();
        }
        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable() {
            PictureDrawable d = new PictureDrawable(mPicture);
            d.setBounds(0, 0, mPicture.getWidth(), mPicture.getHeight());
            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

and layout/drawable_span_test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textSize="50dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#eee"
/>
```

the result is:
[image]

Comment: Can you give me an example with `public ForegroundColorSpan (Parcel src)` contruct, Thanks

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice that "o" is half red and half blue, in this case you could use DynamicDrawableSpan, see my edited answer

Comment: Hi @pskink, can you make textview spanable animation same as ariang karaoke?

Comment: @DuHuynh have no idea of what ariang karaoke is

Comment: Hi @pskink follow this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qE3egNettY, i want highlight text view same this video. Thanks for reply!

Comment: imho its not spannable, but a custom TextView with a custom onDraw

Comment: Hi @pskink, can you give me some code? I don't have any idea for this

Comment: Use canvas.drawText twice: with two different foreground colors

Comment: How to add some delay when draw text? Same as link which i supply?

Comment: use a Handler and one of *Delayed method

Comment: I want 'process bar' highlight text not 'bock' highlight, same karaoke effect. That is all thing i want

Comment: bock? what bock? no idea what you are talking about

Comment: 'block' mean highlight character by character not as karaoke highlight effect

Comment: so i explained: use canvas.drawText twice, each tume with different foreground color

Comment: Please see this [video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=0qE3egNettY). I want to highlight text same effect in video. That all

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Not exactly what you want but should do the job:

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0030>This is layrics o</font> <font color=#ffff00>f the song</font>";
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: I want highlight a part of "o" character same image. Every body noice color of "o" character. Thanks

Comment: I think then the solution is to use `Canvas` with some clipping.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use android [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html)

For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3514435/1278748)