# How to highlight TextView in Android

Tags: android, string, textview, spannablestring

I would like to highlight a `TextView` and achieve the design shown below.
Does anyone know how to achieve this using a `TextView`?
I took this screenshot from an existing Android app.

[image]

By using this code I get results shown below, which is not what I want:

```
sp.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(color), start, length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

[image]

Comment: This has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a Spannable String:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String  text = "Test"; 
Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(text);
spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 14, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spanText);
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Please check my updated question, BackgroundColorSpan results in something different from what I really want.

Comment: What about letting the style apart from the UI?

Comment: @Tinashe  Did you ever get an answer?  The answers above do not address your question about the needed white space.  I have the same problem and have not been able to find an answer.

Comment: @BobLissner Unfortunately I could not find an answer. But I assume this can only be achieved with css

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to highlight the text with a light color? If that's the case, then simply change the transparency of the color. For example: change the first two FF of `0xFFFFFF00` to something like 80(50 % transparency). So, it would look like `0x80FFFF00`.

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String  text = "Your String"; 
Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(text);
spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0x80FFFF00), 14, 19,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spanText);
```

Here's a relevant [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) regarding hex color transparency.

Comment: this is way better than what I had, Thanks a lot. but still it does not leave the white spaces in-between the sentences as it is in the image.