# highlight in edittext when click Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Now i have a problem about highlight in EditText.
- When i click the second time the highlight it will not work.

This my code

```
tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    tv2.performLongClick();
                }
            });
```

I want to highlight every Onclick.

tv2.performLongClick();
[image]

pic2 highlight it not work
[image]

Comment: you can use a Style.xml if you want to make it highlight at the pressed state . Is that what you want?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? your images does not explain your requirement i guess

Comment: Let me how to ?. I don't know really.Thank you su much.

Comment: I can tell when you explain exactly what you want.so once you click on the editText  view what do you want? make its out line change its color or what?

Comment: I need highlight only number in edittext when i click the position number
(i want event Onclick )

Comment: You should do it onLongclick not onclick.

Comment: The defult os if you want highlight some word you must Longlick but my application must use event Onclick.(requirement customer T-T)

Comment: It may not relate but please look how to highlight it programmatically here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41760328/5241603 And this one too. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7832466/5241603

Comment: Thank you very muchhh all commend.

Comment: @ปรัชญา จารุวณิชกุล  he gave links for the textViews try my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to highlight text inside `editText` 
Insted of `tv2.performLongClick()` 
you can simply use `setSelectAllOnFocus(true)`

> Set the TextView so that when it takes focus, all the text is
>   selected.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            if (!hasFocus) {
             // noFocous
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can also set this option in xml: `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"`