# How to highlight the html,css,js syntax on edittext?

Tags: android, editor, syntax-highlighting

I am making an HTML, CSS and JS editor for android. I want to highlight the tags everytime I typed it. Is there any libraries available for syntax highlighting and how to use it?. I am Using eclipse Mars btw. Thanks!

Comment: Use Android Studio. Eclipse is no longer supported. (Yes, I know this does not answer tour question.)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035/highlight-text-in-textview-or-webview

Answer (score 0):

something like richedit?
have a try on this cwac-richedit:https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit