# Is there a way to italicize certain words when displaing it in a TextView on Android?

Tags: android, textview, italics

My Android app is displaying text in a TextView.

Are there any tags or anything to put around words that I want italicized? I don't need to set the TextView as italics because the whole sentence would be that way, and I only need specific words italicized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html): see [Is there any example about Spanned and Spannable text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159847/is-there-any-example-about-spanned-and-spannable-text) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this isn't a database issue. If this is not a custom app you're working on, you're out of luck. If it is, save the field in the database as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This function sets a string as the text of a TextView and italicizes one or more spans within that string as long as the span or spans are marked with the tags [i] and [/i]. Of course, it can be modified for other types of styling.

```
private void doItalicize(TextView xTextView, String xString) {
        ArrayList<Integer> IndexStart = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> IndexEnd = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<StyleSpan> SpanArray = new ArrayList<>();

        int i = 0;

        do {
            IndexStart.add(i, xString.indexOf("[i]"));
            IndexEnd.add(i, xString.indexOf("[/i]") - 3);
            xString = xString.replaceFirst("\\[i\\]", "");
            xString = xString.replaceFirst("\\[/i\\]", "");
            xTextView.setText(xString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            SpanArray.add(i, new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "i: " + i);
            i++;
        } while (xString.contains("[i]"));

        Spannable xSpannable = (Spannable) xTextView.getText();

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            xSpannable.setSpan(SpanArray.get(j), IndexStart.get(j), IndexEnd.get(j), Spanned
                    .SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution would seem to be to save the content in the database as HTML and then output the HTML in the textview.

See the following article: [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)