# Android Html to TextView

Tags: android, html, parsing, text, webview

I am dealing with the following html

```
<div style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"> My Text </div>
```

When using the class html.fromHtml to display my html into a textview I lose the text properties. How can I display the html in a text view properly?

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159847/is-there-any-example-about-spanned-and-spannable-text

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work..
     int n = escapedHtml.indexOf("<div style='font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;'>");  
     int m = escapedHtml.indexOf("/div");
     if (n!=-1){
     try{
        escapedHtml=escapedHtml.replace("<div style='font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;'>", "<h1>");
        escapedHtml=escapedHtml.replace("</div>", "</h1>");
        
     }
     
     catch (Exception e){
     }
     }

Comment: my solution was - use a web view instead

Answer (score 3):

You should check this,
http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html,
only few tags are supported.

You might have to use some parsers to get the values you want and set them dynamically through the code.