# How to highlight the text using annotation in android onTouchEvent?

Tags: android, annotations

I want to highlight the text using annotation in android onTouchEvent.can anyone know the sample or example for this method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question correctly. but seems you can use spannable here.
For eg check this link in stackoverflow:

[example about spanned & spannable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159847/is-there-any-example-about-spanned-and-spannable-text)