# Custom TextView in android with different color words

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to have a `textview` to have different color for every word? Or even every letter? I tried extending `textview` and creating it but however I thought of the problem is, how would I draw all the the text out at the same time with different colors?

Comment: Yes, with `Html.fromHtml()` See  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1529068/871102

Comment: Thanks Xavi. Html.fromHtml() seems to work in my case. Never tried spannable so ima give that a try first before html.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`android.text.Spannable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html)

```
final SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
str.setSpan(
    new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 
    wordStart, 
    wordEnd, 
    SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
);
myTextView.setText(str);
```

**EDIT**: To make all "Java" green

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Java");
final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text);

final SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
final ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
while (matcher.find()) {
    spannable.setSpan(
        span, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    );
}
myTextView.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: How would i set span if I wanted all the "Java" in the textview to be green?

Comment: To do that you have to use regular expressions. See edited answer.

Comment: One more follow up question. Am i able to put "spannable" into another loop? and set another string to a different color?

Comment: SpanableStringBuilder is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got most of the problems solved from this.

Answer (score 21):

The `SpannableString` class allows you to easily format certain pieces (spans) of a string one way and other pieces another by applying extensions of CharacterStyle (i.e. `ForegroundColorSpan`) via the `setSpan` method.

You can try This:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    richTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rich_text);

    // this is the text we'll be operating on
    SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");

    // make "Lorem" (characters 0 to 5) red
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);

    // make "ipsum" (characters 6 to 11) one and a half time bigger than the textbox
    text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 6, 11, 0);

    // make "dolor" (characters 12 to 17) display a toast message when touched
    final Context context = this;
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "dolor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    text.setSpan(clickableSpan, 12, 17, 0);

    // make "sit" (characters 18 to 21) struck through
    text.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 18, 21, 0);

    // make "amet" (characters 22 to 26) twice as big, green and a link to this site.
    // it's important to set the color after the URLSpan or the standard
    // link color will override it.
    text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 22, 26, 0);
    text.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.chrisumbel.com"), 22, 26, 0);
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 22, 26, 0);

    // make our ClickableSpans and URLSpans work
    richTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    // shove our styled text into the TextView        
    richTextView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

For more detail see Chris Umbel [blog](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this with [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) and [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html). See [Is there any example about Spanned and Spannable text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159847/is-there-any-example-about-spanned-and-spannable-text) for one example.

For the various ways to format text (background color, foreground color, clickable, etc.), see [CharacterStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html).