# spannable on android for textView

Tags: java, android, twitter, spannable

```
Tweet o = tweets.get(position);

TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
//TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);         

EditText bt =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
bt.setText(o.author);
Spannable spn = (Spannable) bt.getText();
spn.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
, 0, 100, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);  

//bt.setText(o.author);    
tt.setText(o.content);
```

I'm setting twitter data in my Android application. I want to make the font bold and italic using Spannable but it does not work, giving an error. How can I do it?

Comment: it gives has stopped unexpectedly error. normally code working but I want to make the font bold . ıt gıves this error.

Comment: pls post LogCat output with the exception. Most likely you're trying to apply the span beyond the text end - use actual length instead of 100

Comment: this method may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/44255840/3496570

Answer (score 78, accepted):

> I want to make the font bold and ıtalic with spannable

for this u will need to make `o.content` text as `SpannableString` then set it to TextView as :

```
SpannableString spannablecontent=new SpannableString(o.content.toString());
spannablecontent.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), 
                         0,spannablecontent.length(), 0);
// set Text here
tt.setText(spannablecontent);
```

**EDIT :**
you can also use Html.fromHtml for making text Bold and Italic in textview as :

```
tt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<strong><em>"+o.content+"</em></strong>"));
```

Comment: spannablecontent.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), 
                         0,spannablecontent.length(), 0);

Comment: @baran : you can also use `Html.fromHtml` for making text bold and italic

Comment: how i can add the image here. is there any way to add the image the same way as the text is been made bold?

Comment: @Aada :  just use `ImageSpan` , make a search on Google for *ImageSpan* u will get lots of results

Comment: How can one use a custom font?

Comment: @slott That's a different question altogether. Google it, there are plenty of answers for similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to create a `spannable` text `bold` and `italic` to set into your `TextView` is using the method `Html.fromHtml()`:

and using the html elements `<b>` and `<i>`

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><i>my text bold and italic!</i></b>"));
```

or the html elements `<strong>` and `<em>`

```
   myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<strong><em>my text bold and italic!</em></strong>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SpannableString hint = new SpannableString(o.content.toString());
```

Font size

```
hint.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.9f), 0, hint.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Font family

```
hint.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif"), 0, hint.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

italic

```
hint.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, s.length(), 0);
```

color

```
hint.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, hint.length(), 0);
```

bold

```
hint.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, hint.length(), 0);
```

Reference link:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan