# highlight a certain word in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

Do anyone know how to highlight a certain word in a TextView?

With highligt I mean to use an italic typeface for the word "Hua Hin" in the following string.

The sandy beaches of *Hua Hin*, popular resort town in Thailand.

Must I use a textView in another textView to acomplish this?

I set the text in the onPostExecute-method of AsyncTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] bitmap) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < nmbrOfImages; i++) {
       imageView[i].setImageBitmap(bitmap[i]);
       textView[i].setText(scrollText[i]);
       textView[i].setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    }
    loadAlertDialog();
 }
```

I have all my text in an xml-file

Answer (score 1):

If only italic you want then you can go for

```
textView[i].setText(Html.fromHtml(<i>some part</i> some other text);
```

else you can go for Spnnable

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840247/spannable-on-android-for-textview) is an example in this answer.