# Apply different size string/text to TextView

Tags: android, textview

[image]

I have a text '$170.00' and I want to apply this text to TextView as shown in image.
How could be it possible.?? Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just want to put that there, why not try a imageview instead?

Comment: Look at http://vnamashko.blogspot.in/2012/04/rich-textview.html

Comment: @Gautham this is price which is dynamically calculted according to product quantity.So i cant use ImageView.Thanx

Comment: @Vicky, try my below solution and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Create a `SpannableString` from your original text

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString(originalText)
```

2) Set a `SuperscriptSpan` and a `RelativeSizeSpan` for the `$` symbol

```
string.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
string.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((0.5f), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

3) Leave the integer part alone.

4) Get the index for the decimal part and apply a `SuperscriptSpan` and a `RelativeSizeSpan` to it.

```
string.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), originalText.lenght - 2, originalText.lenght - 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
string.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((0.5f),  originalText.lenght - 2, originalText.lenght - 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

5) Apply the `SpannableString` to the `TextView`

```
textView.setText(string);
```

Comment: Nop it looks like SuperScript for 170.

Comment: What? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a RelativeSizeSpan. Try different values for the RelativeSizeSpan constructor to accomodate your needs.

Comment: Yup i got the output close to what I looking for using your snippet. Still '$' sign looks like Superscript. Thanks for help buddy. Please let me know if u get the correct solution.

Comment: Is $ not supposed to be superscript? If this answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Try it something like below.

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("<sup>$</sup>170<sup>00</sup>"));
```

with `sup` the text is going UP and with `sub` the text is going down.

Comment: Nop it looks like SuperScript for 170.

Comment: @Vicky, obviously it will look like that only, what else you want then.

Comment: They should look on same lavel.

Comment: Hi I know it can be done using HTML Style. and I have written code for it but don't know how to use it. If u know then can u tell me how to use it?  I will post the html code.

Comment: /*  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
  <title>Untitled Document</title> 
  <style> 
  h1{ font-family:Avenir; size:20px; vertical-align:text-top; margin:0; padding:0;} 
  sup{ font-family:Avenir; size:18px; vertical-align:text-top; padding-top:2px;} 
   
  </style> 
   
  </head> 
  <body> 
  <h1><sup>$</sup> 170 <sup>00</sup></h1> 
  </body> 
  </html> 
*/

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpannableString to format content of TextView:

[SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Or you could use three different TextView in horizontal LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

it will be done by spannable text what you want to do. but i dont know much about spannable text.

see here [spannable on android for textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840247/spannable-on-android-for-textview)

may be this may give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can through layout XML as follows...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/second_text"
        android:text="$"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_text"
        android:text="170"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/third_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/second_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second_text"
        android:text="OO"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```