# What are all the types of '✔️' characters available on Android ? (for a TextView)

Tags: java, android, unicode, character-encoding, character

I wonder what are all the types of '✔️' characters available on Android (for a TextView)

Nota : I need to be able to change their color (I just saw that it is impossible to change the color for some of them)

Thanks !

Comment: Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You did not add any code.

Comment: Some font with a check mark symbol `\u2713`. Such a symbol can then be colored. You need to do rich text.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

### Set text and color in XML:

All of the chars in `TextView` will have same color - your char (✔️) also. You can extract your char to `strings.xml` to reuse it in few places.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="✔"
    android:textColor="#f0f"
    android:textSize="100sp" />
```

[image: Char]

---

### Set text programatically

Char from the (Java) code

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textView.setText("\u2713");
```

But color (`#0F0`) was set in XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#0F0"
    android:textSize="100sp" />
```

[image: XML]

---

### Using `SpannableString`

So you can change color only the part of the string.

```
String first = "stack";
String second = "overflow";
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(first + "\u2713" + second);

ForegroundColorSpan color = new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_red_dark));

spannable.setSpan(
        color,
        first.length(),
        first.length() + 1,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textView.setText(spannable);
```

In XML there is only empty `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#00F"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```

There are many post how to use `SpannableString` mechanism:

- [Android Spanned, SpannedString, Spannable, SpannableString and CharSequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546955/android-spanned-spannedstring-spannable-spannablestring-and-charsequence/17547344#17547344)
- [spannable on android for textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840247/spannable-on-android-for-textview/14840432#14840432)

[image: spannable]