# How find anchor Link from String?

Tags: java, android, xml, anchor

I am new in Android now want how find anchor link tag from strings for example I have string like this which have some discrption and link

```
string product_distription="Buy this awesome " Thumb Design Mobile OK Stand Holder Universal For All 
here input
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" >Buy now</a>

"
ouput: http://stackoverflow.com
```

Now only want extract link only from this string becuase I have app which have descrption link coming from PHP & MySQL and show in Android textview with link so now I only want know if discrption including any HTML anchor tag it will extract from the discrption only can extract not whole discrption only show this link

Comment: Use SpannableString: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568:

Comment: or use html in string file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840247/spannable-on-android-for-textview

Comment: and set click for spanablestring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(extractAnchorLinks(
                "This <a href=\"www.google.com\">search engine</a> is the most popular. This <a href=\"www.stackoverflow.com\"> website is the largest online community for developers</a>There are millions of websites today"));
    }

    public static List<String> extractAnchorLinks(String string) {
        List<String> anchorLinkList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final String TAG = "a href=\"";
        final int TAG_LENGTH = TAG.length();
        int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;
        String nextSubstring = "";
        do {
            startIndex = string.indexOf(TAG);
            if (startIndex != -1) {
                nextSubstring = string.substring(startIndex + TAG_LENGTH);
                endIndex = nextSubstring.indexOf("\">");
                if (endIndex != -1) {
                    anchorLinkList.add(nextSubstring.substring(0, endIndex));
                }
                string = nextSubstring;
            }
        } while (startIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1);
        return anchorLinkList;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[www.google.com, www.stackoverflow.com]
```

The logic is straight forward. Moreover, the variable names are also self-explantory. Nevertheless, feel free to comment in case of any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

```
 fun getLinkFromString() {
    val content = "visit this link: www.google.com"
    val splitted = content.split(" ")
    for (i in splitted.indices) {
        if (splitted[i].contains("www.") || splitted[i].contains("http://")) {
            println(splitted[i]) //just checking the output
            val link = "<a href=\"" + splitted[i] + "\">" + splitted[i] + "</a>"
            println(link)
            Toast.makeText(this, link, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

This may help you to achieve similar.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.