# Bold content not showing bold

Tags: android, android-webview

I am newbie in android. When I am  getting the data from an URL then parse the HTML data and show the page contents using `loadDataWithBaseURL()`.
But it's showing all data with the same formatting.

I used HTML tags in data.
The paragraph tag `<p>` and other tags are working fine, but the bold tag is not showing the contents in bold. I used `<b>` and `</b>` for bold.

How to show bold content as bold?

Here is the java code.

```
 final String ftext = "<html><body>"+ Html.fromHtml(storyText)+ "   </body></html>";
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", ftext, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
                webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Are you loading HTML data from url ?

Comment: I cant see any  `<b> </b>` in your code.

Comment: @Kristo1990 those tags are probably found inside `storyText`

Comment: The thing is that if he hasn't included `<b> </b>` in his `storyText` then it will never be bold :) @Hrundi V. Bakshi

Comment: Let's give him the benefit of doubt ;)

Comment: yes, storytext is a string variable and I am getting whole data in this variable after parse whole string using Html.fromHtml() function.

Comment: okay mate take a look on this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold
you might find the solution there because it is quite simple. Good luck.

Comment: @Kristo1990 All tags available in the data first I took all the Data as a string then parse  the data using Html.fromHtml() function.

Comment: Yes take a look at the link I posted above please. It is all you need.

Comment: @Kristo1990 I d'nt want whole data bold only those content inside <b>content</b> should be bold this is my problem

Comment: @Vijay Prakash then pass only the data you want to be bold in your String...

Comment: `Html.fromHtml("This mixes <b>your text/ID/whatever</b> and <i>this part will be italic.</i> stuff");`
 something like this i guess would work.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi, I included <b> </b> in my data becuase <p> </p> wherever I used its working fine only I have problem with bold tags

Comment: Weird. Unless you're using *a font which doesn't have the bold glyphs*, it MUST work.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi, This is data fomat <br><br><b>This is the headline</b><br><br><div align="justify">story content <br><br><b> other story headline</b><br><br>.<br><br>whole story<br><br>.

Comment: Which **font** are you using?

Comment: Thanks Hrundi V. Bakshi,I am using Calibri font and showing whole data in webview.

Comment: Thanks @HrundiV.Bakshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, you're using the font `Calibri`.

Calibri is not a monolithic, self contained font.
It's split into multiple ttf files, one per each variant.

So you have to include all of them or at least the ones you intend to use.

i.e.:

> calibri.ttf
>   calibrib.ttf