# Bold characters in string.xml are not shown on screen

Tags: android, xml, string-formatting

In my string.xml file, I have something like this:

```
<string name="example_string"><b>This</b> is a <b>%1$s</b></string>
```

And then I placed it into a TextView:

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.example_string, "good question"));
```

The "good question" argument that I passed to the `getString()` method is not shown in **bold**. Even the word "This" is not shown in bold!
What's the reason for this and how to solve it?

=========================================================================

**I know how to use Html.fromHtml(), but this method does not support inserting a string to the place holder that I have defined in the string resource. If you are trying to tell me that Html.fromHtml() exists, please DO NOT REPLY...**

Comment: I think getString() method somehow deletes or wipes out all the formatting information stored in string resouce when it returns the result... So I guess a better question to ask is: Is there a better method out there that is able to fill the place holder in string resource while keep the formatting information in there?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So after a day of search, I found the desired answer on Android Developers website! The Link to the page is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

> Sometimes you may want to create a styled text resource that is also used as a format string. Normally, this won't work because the String.format(String, Object...) method will strip all the style information from the string. The work-around to this is to write the HTML tags with escaped entities, which are then recovered with fromHtml(String), after the formatting takes place.

Basicaly, the change that I would make based on my original question is to replace the bracket "<" with the HTML tag for that, which is **"&lt" + ";"** (Type them together in your xml file! I had to separate them because StackOverflow will diplay the tag as the bracket itself.) For more detailed explanation, please see the **Styling with HTML markup** section from the website that I posted above.

Comment: That was the only thing that worked out for me, thanks.

Comment: I had to do something like this: `HtmlCompat.fromHtml(@string/resource(variable), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)` within in my xml. I also imported `HtmlCompat` in the `<data>` section

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource
it recommends that you escape html

Answer (score 10):

i've had success using [getText instead of getString](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource).  It seems to maintain styling.

[from the docs:](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource)

> You can use either getString(int) or getText(int) to retrieve a
>   string. getText(int) retains any rich text styling applied to the
>   string.

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

You need to format the text using [Html.fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) or using a [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

`Html.fromHtml` example:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.example_string, "good question")));
```

**Edit:**

If you're having trouble passing the tags through, its because it needs to be escaped by `CDATA`.

eg.  `<string name="example_string">This is a <![CDATA[<b>%1$s</b>]]></string>`

Comment: Sorry I tried this but did not work, thanks for replying though!

Comment: You need to place your Html in CDATA

Comment: Thanks for the reply! On my screen it is showing <b>good question</b> instead of "good question" in bold font. Did I do something wrong potentially?

Comment: I have found the correct answer to this problem. Please see the answer that I have posted!

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
String myString = "This is a " + "<b>" + "your_string" + "</b>"; 
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString));
```

for more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know this technically SHOULD work, (and normally I would use this method), but in this case I must use the getString() method to fill in the place holder that's stored in the string resource.

Comment: try to set directly in your xml

Comment: That's exactly what I did in the first place... The <b></b> simply got wiped out after getString() method inserted my string to the place holder.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this below

```
String boldText = "Hello"+"<b>" + "StackOverflow" + "</b>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(boldText));
```

Now your text look like this : Hello **StackOverflow**

See this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String))

Comment: Hi I know how to use Html.fromHtml()... It's just I don't want to use hard-coded string, and instead put my string in the resource folder and then fill the place holder in the code (This is also a better programming practice :))

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin:
`binding.titleTextView.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml("This is a " + "<b>" + "your_string" + "</b>",HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)`

Answer (score -1):

```
use this... it will working.

/**
 * Makes a substring of a string bold.
 * @param text          Full text
 * @param textToBold    Text you want to make bold
 * @return              String with bold substring
 */

public static SpannableStringBuilder makeSectionOfTextBold(String text, String textToBold){

    SpannableStringBuilder builder=new SpannableStringBuilder();

    if(textToBold.length() > 0 && !textToBold.trim().equals("")){

        //for counting start/end indexes
        String testText = text.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        String testTextToBold = textToBold.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        int startingIndex = testText.indexOf(testTextToBold);
        int endingIndex = startingIndex + testTextToBold.length();
        //for counting start/end indexes

        if(startingIndex < 0 || endingIndex <0){
            return builder.append(text);
        }
        else if(startingIndex >= 0 && endingIndex >=0){

            builder.append(text);
            builder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startingIndex, endingIndex, 0);
        }
    }else{
        return builder.append(text);
    }

    return builder;
```

Comment: Thanks dude, at least you are not thinking that I don't even know about Html... This method is cumbersome though. I have already defined what should be bold in my string resource, so I guess the best solution would be more towards showing the <b></b> that I have defined on screen :)