# Is it possible to only change only a part of a TextView?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

A little more specific.
I want to know if it is possible to update a number that is saved in a  `TextView` or if I have to use two `TextViews`.
What I have atm in the XML-File:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/UpInfo"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Upgrade: 0 "/>
```

Now I want to change the 0 in `android:text` while the App is running. Is this possible? If yes how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this may help you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold

Answer (score 4):

Use a variable and string concatenation:

```
int number = 1;
TextView textview = (TextView) findviewbyId(R.id.UpInfo);

textview.setText("Upgrade: " + number);
```

Or if you use a method like this:

```
public void updateText(int number){
  textview.setText("Upgrade: " + number);
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
updateText(2);
```

Result... Upgrade: 2

```
updateText(3);
```

Result.... Upgrade: 3

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can use `Spannable` string

```
final SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(your string);

spannable.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
txtView.setText(spannable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be achieved using `Spannable` strings.

Find relevant examples in the link below:

http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html

Comment: The link you shared is broken