# Android SpannableString(Builder) does not apply style

Tags: java, android, spannablestring, textstyle

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder(decimalFormat.format(prizes[0])
    + "€");
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(BOLD), 0, str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

money.setText("paid | " + str);
```

This code should produce the same result as this code

```
money.setText(Html.fromHtml("paid | <strong>" + decimalFormat.format(prizes[0]) 
    + "€</strong>")
```

But it does not! My text does **not** come out **bold**.
The `fromHtml()` one does make it bold like this:
[image]
This is how I want it to appear because over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold#14371141) they said that it is better in performance and I want to use native android funtions.
Using `SpannableStringBuilder` it displays like this:
[image]With nothing bold. I also tried just using `SpannableString` instead of `SpannableStringBuilder`, but that didn't change anything either. What am I doing wrong?

My `money` variable is a `TextView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I was sure that I tried that before, but it works like this: `textView.setText(spannableStringBuilder)` instead of `textView.setText(someString + spannableStringBuilder)`.

So my code now is like this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("paid | "
    +  decimalFormat.format(prizes[0]) + "€");
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(BOLD), 7, str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

money.setText(str);
```

Comment: Correct. The `+` operator is *string* concatenation, which converts `str` from a `SpannableStringBuilder` to a plain unformatted string. Use `TextUtils.concat()` to concatenate multiple `CharSequence` objects together, which works with `String` and `Spannable` objects, maintaining your spans.

Comment: or `SpannableStringBuilder#insert()` method

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with you are setting a string at last of the money textview. It should be a spanned string.

Check with this one:

```
String sMoney = decimalFormat.format(prizes[0]) + "€";

SpannableString styledString = new SpannableString("paid | " + sMoney);
```

//This line of code is important because I added "paid | " in spannable string

```
styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 7, styledString.length, 0);

money.setText(styledString);
```