# How to make one part of the text Bold in iText

Tags: android, itext

I need to get a part of the text bold in my app.  So basically what I am trying to achieve is have something like this:  **Address:** 123 Street.  Where at the moment i am getting all in bold:  **Address: 123 Street**

Here is my code I am using:

```
PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(3);
            table2.setWidthPercentage(100);
            table2.addCell(getCell("Address:  " + SaveString, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            table2.addCell(getCell("Name:  " + SaveStringA, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
            table2.addCell(getCell("Last Name:  " + SaveStringB, PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT));
            table2.setSpacingAfter(15);
            doc.add(table2);  

public PdfPCell getCell(String text, int alignment) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
    Font bold = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 12, Font.BOLD);
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(text, bold);
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.addElement(p1);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);

    return cell;
```

Hoping someone could help please?

Thanks!!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371107/4582676

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  But I have tried that and not working :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can try using Chunk, something like this:

```
Font bold = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 12, Font.BOLD);
Chunk chunkAddress= new Chunk("Address:  ", bold);
Chunk ChunkAddressDetails = new Chunk("123 Street.");

Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.add(chunkAddress);
phrase.add(ChunkAddressDetails);

Paragraph paragraph= = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(phrase);
```

Comment: That looks sensible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("Address: 123 Street");
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, "Address:".length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
yourTextView.setText(str);
```

Comment: Thanks,  But when testing it doesn't seem to work :-(