# How customize app_name style in navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like have a title 50% strong and 50% normal. Is this possibile?

Answer (score 0):

You can do same thing 
like here: [how to make a specific text on TextView BOLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold)

`String sourceString = "<b>" + First part + "</b> " + second part; 
getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));`