# Make multiple parts of string bold in a textview dynamically in kotlin

Tags: android, textview

I multiple strings in the following format.
 - "the *quick* brown fox *jumps* over the lazy *dog* "
I want to show them as
 - "the **quick** brown fox **jumps** over the lazy **dog** "

in a recyclerview adapter
how can that be done I have no clue how to begin.

Comment: if you search `Make multiple parts of string bold` your first result should be this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold/14371107, does that help ?

Comment: I kinda see the steps I have to find all the indexes of *.  if the *'s exist I need to make the text b/w the indexes bold and remove the * themselves. seems it will slow down the app is there a good example how that can be done??

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SpannableString

```
val spannableString = SpannableString("Here this is for span string example!")
val loc = spannableString.toString().indexOf("s")
spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), loc, 3, 
Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
hint_textView!!.setText(spannableString.toString())
```

Comment: I see but there are multiple occurances of * in my string how do I get the indexes of all of them