# How to remove current typeface for some lines only

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an arraylist that will print the array into a textview. I loop it with for loop and print it win `Textview.append("my text)"`. I'm trying to set the first item as bold so i tried `Textview.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);`. I want the next lines to be normal so I set it again as `Textview.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);` after the first append, but it all stayed as bold.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a specific text on TextView BOLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold) (do not use HtmlCompat, use a `Span`)

Comment: Thanks! Tried span but didn't work. Html one worked for me.

Comment: Html is very slow compared to a Span (and has other issues) but if it works for you, then that's ok. The Span works, I can assure you, I've done the exact same thing before :) Good luck.