# SpannableStringBuilder setting String partially as bold not working

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannablestringbuilder

I'm using SpannableStringBuilder to set a string partially with a style of bold, however it's not working and I am unsure of what I am doing incorrectly.

```
String normalText = "New Here? ";
String boldText = "Register";
        
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder(normalText + boldText);
tr.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), normalText.length(), str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mBtnRegister.setText(str);
```

I've followed this SO example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460376/11110509

Comment: This seems to be working well, see here https://imgur.com/a/1cOLQrC

Comment: Ive figured out the error, it was a stupid mistake in the XML lol
It won't let me close the bounty question though

Comment: then grant the bounty :D

Comment: post your answer and ill give you it

Comment: Thanks for this. You may post your own answer and accept that as a solution. I can't take 50 points for free :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specified code looks to be working well as visible in the screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZX7G.jpg

Please check your code for other mistakes causing wrong behavior.