# How to make the first character much larger than other in a TextView

Tags: android

I would like to display a paragraph of long text as follow. Here is the snapshot from Flipboard.

[image]

In order to achieve such effect, I tried to use 2 `TextView`s.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="T" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="op British supermarket Tesco (LSE: TSCO) (NASDAQOTH: TSCDY.US) is due to announce its half year results on" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get the following result.

Quite close. But not what I want. This is because the 2nd line and the 3rd line is not align to the left most. The left most space for 2nd line and 3rd line, is occupied by the `TextView` with large font.

[image]

Is there any better technique I can use, such as the one in Flipboard's?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159847/is-there-any-example-about-spanned-and-spannable-text

Comment: Just use `HTML` tags and load your data with `Html.fromHtml()` in `TextView` or either in `WebView`.

Comment: @Andrew Spannable text is a great idea. Thanks. I added that as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a single `TextView` with `BufferType.SPANNABLE` will solve the problem.

```
final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(title);
int position = 0;
for (int i = 0, ei = title.length(); i < ei; i++) {
    char c = title.charAt(i);
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')) {
        position = i;
        break;
    }
}
spannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f), position, position + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//titleTextView.setText(spannableString.toString());
titleTextView.setText(spannableString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me probably you have use 3 TextViews: 
1 - Paragraph Letter
2 - first and second line
3 - rest of the text.

Comment: But in your Java code, how can you determine which content to place at which text views?

Comment: It's good to use WebView in it, but I probably won't do this. You need to find out how much of the text will fill up the first 2 TextViews and after it subtract the string. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864159/count-words-in-a-string-method .

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bigChar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="T"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sideText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigChar"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="2" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spillText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/bigChar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_below="@id/bigChar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String inputString = "op British supermarket Tesco (LSE: TSCO) (NASDAQOTH: TSCDY.US) is due to announce its half year results on and this is the extra bit of spill text";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView bigChar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bigChar);
    final TextView sideText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sideText);
    final TextView spillText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spillText);


    ViewTreeObserver vto = sideText.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
           Layout layout = sideText.getLayout();  
           int numOfLines = layout.getLineEnd(2);

           // split the string now
           String spillTextString = inputString.substring(numOfLines, inputString.length());
           spillText.setText(spillTextString);
        }
    });
}
}
```