# Text alignment with an image as mentioned in design - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to implement following design on android, D is either an image or a character. Text should be properly aligned as mentioned in design. Any suggestions?

[image]

I tried it using left drawable of textview, custom icon of radio button and checkbox but text alignment is an issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030843/how-to-make-the-first-character-much-larger-than-other-in-a-textview

Comment: You could use spannable text for same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one it will give you same result

https://github.com/rpradal/Lettrine

Add this in your gradle

```
compile 'com.github.rpradal.lettrine:lettrine:release_number'
```

In you XML just add

```
<com.github.rpradal.lettrine.LettrineTextView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:lettrine_textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
              app:lettrine_text="Lorem ipsum"
              app:lettrine_lettrineSize="3"
              app:lettrine_textSize="14sp" />
```

[image]