# Capitalize and enlarge the first letter of TextView in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How to make the first letter of a text in a `textView` large and capital using android studio like the one in the attached image.

[image: this is the image]

Comment: You're going to need at least a customTextLayout, if not a custom TextView.  That isn't any type of built in feature.

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030843/how-to-make-the-first-character-much-larger-than-other-in-a-textview), there is a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

100% work

Steps!

1) Use this library

```
             compile 'com.novoda:drop-cap:1.1.0'
```

2) Define it in your layout

```
    <com.novoda.dropcap.DropCapView
        android:id="@+id/view_drop_cap"
        style="@style/DropCap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button1_detail" />
```

3) Define it into your styles.xml

```
<style name="DropCap">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/drop_cap_padding_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/drop_cap_padding_top</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/drop_cap_padding_right</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/drop_cap_padding_bottom</item>
    <item name="dropCapTextSize">@dimen/drop_cap_text</item>
    <item name="numberOfDropCaps">1</item>
    <item name="dropCapFontPath">fonts/SANS-SERIF_Cabin-Regular.otf</item>
    <item name="copyTextSize">@dimen/copy_text</item>
    <item name="copyFontPath">fonts/neuropolitical_rg.ttf</item>
    <item name="lineSpacingExtra">@dimen/drop_cap_linespacing_extra</item>
</style>
```

4)Define it into your dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="drop_cap_padding_left">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="drop_cap_padding_top">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="drop_cap_padding_right">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="drop_cap_padding_bottom">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="drop_cap_text">64sp</dimen>
<dimen name="copy_text">21sp</dimen>
<dimen name="scroll_view_height">200dp</dimen>
<dimen name="divider_height">1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="drop_cap_linespacing_extra">0sp</dimen>
```

4) In your java code just findItById and set Text.

Reference->   https://github.com/novoda/drop-cap

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code snippet, this will help you.

```
String str = "sample text";

//Change first character to capital letter
String tempStr = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);

//Change font size of the first character. You can change 2f as you want
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(tempStr);
spannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//Set the formatted text to text view
tvSample.setText(spannableString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
String upperString = myString.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + myString.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one textView for character A and another textView for rest of text. 
i don't think is there any code to write like this because of alignment.