# Android Textview Italic and wrap_contents

Tags: android, textview, bold, text-styling, italics

I am using 3 italic textviews with different colors

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/submittedBy" android:paddingTop="10dip">


            <ImageView android:id="@+id/subByImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:src="@drawable/submitted_by_arrow"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/submitLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left" android:text="Submitted by"  android:textStyle="italic"
                android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="@color/gray" android:paddingLeft="5dip"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/submitName" android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="@color/maroon_dark" android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/submitByDate" android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="@color/gray" android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

I wonder every last character is not displaying properly specially name displayed in the middle is "Dan Buckland" and it it is missing last character looks like "Dan Bucklano"

Also tell me pls how can have textview italic and bold both..

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/953d573113.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/953d573113.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the bounding box is not correctly calculated when using italic.

Have you tried to use paddingLeft=6 and paddingRight=6 for the elements?
(less chance of overlap).

For multiple styles in a TextView see [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/android-is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem.  I got around it by simply adding a space to the end of any string that needs to be in italics.

It may not be the most long-term-correct solution but it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, that works. Use one extra space or have "fill_parent" as width. Shame this is not handled correctly by Android (mine is 2.3.7).

Comment: You'll have to use \u0020 to force a space if you're using XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&#160;` with the text in string.xml file.