# View "cuts" a TextView that's in the same LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

[image: The cut textview]

Hi! I'm using a ListView to show the information stored in a SQL Database, this ListView has two TextViews.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/productlist_adapter_producto" 
    style="@style/normalText" 
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/productlist_adapter_info" 
     android:textSize="14sp" 
     android:textColor="@color/Gris"
     android:textStyle="italic"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/espacio"/>
</LinearLayout>

<style name="espacio">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
</style>
```

Why the View "espacio" cuts the inferior textview?

Comment: What does the `espacio`-styled view do?

Comment: How do you inflate "espacio" - styled view?
btw.. beicon? Joder tio ;)

Comment: espacio fill the area that's not filled by the others views. I use it to can do click on all the area of the ListView.

Comment: This is a known issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4353836/1321873 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2271109/1321873

Comment: PD: For my spanish friend: Beicon también lo recoje la RAE xD

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Rajesh, It's the same problem, I've fixed perfectly, thanks again!