# Highlighting Text Color using Html.fromHtml() in Android?

Tags: android, text, highlight, textview

I am developing an application in which there will be a search screen
where user can search for specific keywords and that keyword should be
highlighted. I have found Html.fromHtml method.

But I will like to know whether its the proper way of doing it or
not.

Please let me know your views on this.

Comment: check out for an working example. http://javatechig.com/2013/04/07/how-to-display-html-in-android-view/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Or far simpler than dealing with `Spannable`s manually, since you didn't say that you want the background highlighted, just the text:

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: It's worth noting, that Html.fromHtml is slower than SpannableString, because it involves parsing. But for a short text it doesn't matter

Comment: There appears to be another solution at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview).  See the answer by Legend.

Comment: Just as a comment, I found I didn't need to pass TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE and it still worked. Thanks!

Comment: do you know any html editor for arrenging long text for android. for example I am trying to use this site (http://www.html.am/html-editors/html-text-editor.cfm) but if I want to see source it returns color as `<span style="color:#ff0000;">` so that android dont change the color.

Comment: @mehmet You could presumably just search and replace to change the <span> tags to <font> tags with a "color" attribute.

Comment: Clarification for those who wonders how to use specific hex color in html:
`<font color='#aabbcc'>text</font>`

Comment: @JohnnyFive I am trying to change <a tag text color. But it is not working for me. It always set color to app accent color. any suggestion?

Answer (score 44):

Using color value from xml resource:

```
int labelColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.label_color);
String сolorString = String.format("%X", labelColor).substring(2); // !!strip alpha value!!

Html.fromHtml(String.format("<font color=\"#%s\">text</font>", сolorString), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: nicely done. useful to be able to use colors from your apps resources.

Comment: I want to stress second line, where you substring the color hex: alpha value would make the color setting invalid! Don't forget it!

Answer (score 13):

This can be achieved using a Spannable String. You will need to import the following

```
import android.text.SpannableString; 
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan; 
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
```

And then you can change the background of the text using something like the following:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_login);
text.setText("");
text.append("Your text here");
Spannable sText = (Spannable) text.getText();
sText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 1, 4, 0);
```

Where this will highlight the charecters at pos 1 - 4 with a red color. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

font is deprecated use span instead `Html.fromHtml("<span style=color:red>"+content+"</span>")`

Answer (score 5):

Alternative solution: Using a WebView instead. Html is easy to work with.

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);

String summary = "<html><body>Sorry, <span style=\"background: red;\">Madonna</span> gave no results</body></html>";

webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: because of fromHTML() limitations, I'm heading for a tablet app with text in every panel displayed in a WebView. Welcome to the 2020s, where everything's a web page including your tablet's text view!~

Answer (score 5):

```
 String name = modelOrderList.get(position).getName();   //get name from List
    String text = "<font color='#000000'>" + name + "</font>"; //set Black color of name
    /* check API version, according to version call method of Html class  */
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: if");
        holder.textViewName.setText(context.getString(R.string._5687982) + " ");
        holder.textViewName.append(Html.fromHtml(text));
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: else");
        holder.textViewName.setText("123456" + " ");   //set text 
        holder.textViewName.append(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));   //append text into textView
    }
```

Comment: how to get the font color from color.xml  ?

Comment: int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.any_color_name);

Answer (score 1):

To make part of your text underlined and colored

in your strings.xml

```
<string name="text_with_colored_underline">put the text here and &lt;u>&lt;font color="#your_hexa_color">the underlined colored part here&lt;font>&lt;u></string>
```

then in the activity

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_with_colored_underline)));
```

and for clickable links:

```
<string name="text_with_link"><![CDATA[<p>text before link<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">title of link</a>.<p>]]></string>
```

and in your activity:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_with_link)));
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

First Convert your string into HTML then convert it into spannable. do as suggest the following codes.

```
 Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(labelText));
                    
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(color)), spannable.toString().indexOf("•"), spannable.toString().lastIndexOf("•") + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='rgb'>"+text contain+"</font>"));
```

It will give the color exactly what you have made in html editor , just set the textview and concat it with the textview value. Android does not support span color, change it to font color in editor and you are all set to go.

Answer (score 0):

Adding also Kotlin version with:

- getting text from resources (`strings.xml`)
- getting color from resources (`colors.xml`)
- "fetching HEX" moved as extension

```
fun getMulticolorSpanned(): Spanned {
    // Get text from resources
    val text: String = getString(R.string.your_text_from_resources)

    // Get color from resources and parse it to HEX (RGB) value
    val warningHexColor = getHexFromColors(R.color.your_error_color)

    // Use above string & color in HTML
    val html = "<string>$text<span style=\"color:#$warningHexColor;\">*</span></string>"

    // Parse HTML (base on API version)
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
    } else {
        Html.fromHtml(html)
    }
}
```

And Kotlin extension (with removing alpha):

```
fun Context.getHexFromColors(
    colorRes: Int
): String {
    val labelColor: Int = ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)
    return String.format("%X", labelColor).substring(2)
}
```

## Demo

[image: demo]