# Using size HTML attribute in TextView

Tags: android

I have the following:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\" size=\"24\">Hello</font>"));
```

The string 'Hello' does turn red but the size does not change.

It is as if the size attribute is just ignored, does anyone know why this is? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, size attribute just ignored. Only "color" and "face" attributes are taken into account.

From [`Html` class sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/text/Html.java#621):

```
private void handleStartTag(String tag, Attributes attributes) {
    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("br")) {
        // We don't need to handle this. TagSoup will ensure that there's a </br> for each <br>
        // so we can safely emite the linebreaks when we handle the close tag.
    }
    ...
    else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("font")) {
        startFont(mSpannableStringBuilder, attributes);
    }
    ...
}

private static void startFont(SpannableStringBuilder text,
                              Attributes attributes) {
    String color = attributes.getValue("", "color");
    String face = attributes.getValue("", "face");

    int len = text.length();
    text.setSpan(new Font(color, face), len, len, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that, I'll see if there's a XSpan class for changing the font size in a similar manner as they are doing there.

Comment: It's `AbsoluteSizeSpan` class.

Answer (score 16):

Size attribute seems not working.

You can use `<small>` or `<big>`   (multiple times to increase the effect)

You can also use `<h1>`  to `<h6>`  (Header only, i.e. add a new line)

Its old-fashion, but it works well !

Comment: My superscript tag looks like this:
`<small><sup><sup><small><small><small>2</small></small></small></small></sup></sup>`

Answer (score 3):

**Try this one,Its working for me,use small,big key words**

```
TextView mBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#cc0029>" + "<b>"
        + "Hiiiiiiiiii" + "</b>" + "<br />" + "<small>" + "description"
        + "</small>" + "<br />" + "<small>" + "DateAdded" + "</small>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sergey Gotov is right. The only way to change text size it to use `h1` - `h6` tags.

**EDIT**: You can also implement `TagHandler` and use your own tags.

Comment: Yeah I have noticed that too, not quite good enough though really.

Comment: TagHandler.handleTag is not called for H1's it seems.

Answer (score -2):

Look at **Formatting and Styling** on the android developpers site: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Or, on this old post of StackOverflow : 
[Highlighting Text Color using Html.fromHtml() in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730706/highlighting-text-color-using-html-fromhtml-in-android)