# Custom Font on Title in PagerTabStrip using SpannableString

Tags: java, android, fonts, custom-font, spannablestring

I want to set a custom font for the titles in my `PagerTabStrip`. I would like to use a `SpannableString`. Similar to:

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Title Array Here");       
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

My titles are in an array and use `getPageTitle(int position)` in the simple code:

```
String [] titlesArray = new String []{ "Title 1" , "Title 2" , "Title 3"};

public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {    
    return titlesArray [position];
}
```

So my question: How can I set a custom font to my array of titles in my PagerTabStrip using a SpannableString with a TypfaceSpan?

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the other question and answers do not explain how to set the font using a SpannableString with a TypfaceSpan.

Comment: the other questions/answers do also not explain how to set the font to an array of titles.

Comment: have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247113/using-html-in-textview