# Styling with HTML markup, it's not work in strings.xml

Tags: android, string, android-xml

Styling with HTML markup, it's not work in strings.xml and I don't know, why.

```
<string name="autores">This aplication is developed by <i>Charles</i></string>
```

And it set the phrase without italic way in the word Charles.
What could it be the problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can use CDATASection.

**Example:**

```
<string name="autores">
<![CDATA[
This application is developed by <i>Charles</i>
]]>
</string>
```

and

```
dialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(this.getString(R.string.autores)));
```

**Reference:**

[CDATASection](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/CDATASection.html)

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: No need to use CDATA, just replace < with &lt;

Answer (score 0):

The strings.xml file is not meant to be used this way. Use `SpannableString`s programmatically instead. For example: [Highlighting Text Color using Html.fromHtml() in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730706/highlighting-text-color-using-html-fromhtml-in-android)

Comment: Ok, but I want to set in a AlertDialog.Builder

    dialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(this.getString(R.string.phrase)));

Comment: IT's not work!!
dialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(this.getString(R.string.phrase)));

But if I write a normal string, that is working!! Why? Isn't it possible to do it with a text from strings.xml?