# Create a color function

Tags: java, android, input, colors

I need your help to make a **color function**.
I'd like to create something like this

I've an `edittext` and I want to put in color part of string , but with a special input
example :

```
if the user type : ^1Hi ^2Stack^3Over^4Flow !
"Hi" = red color , "Stack" = green color , "Over" = blue color and "Flow" = orange color.
```

how to do this?

Comment: you need to parse such text and replace it with html <font/> tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730706/highlighting-text-color-using-html-fromhtml-in-android

Comment: i've already looked on this post , but i dont know how to know if the symbol "^" has been typed , thanks

Answer (score 2):

[image]You could Use Spannable string to achieve this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

String red = "RedText";
SpannableString str1= new SpannableString(red);
str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, red.length(), 0);
builder.append(str1);

String white = "WhiteText";
SpannableString str2= new SpannableString(white);
str2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, white.length(), 0);
builder.append(str2);

String blue = "BlueText";
SpannableString str3 = new SpannableString(blue);
str3.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, blue.length(), 0);
builder.append(str3);

mTextView.setText(builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Did you tried the code I posted? I attached the screenshot using the above sample. Changed White->Yellow as white on white was not visible.

Comment: great ! but how to do ? and you do it with the input ^x x=number ?

Comment: I dint get it? What do you mean how to?

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>Hi</font>"+" "+"<font color='green'>Stack</font>"+" "+"<font color='blue'>Over</font>"+" "+"<font color='orange'>Flow</font>";

textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```

Comment: Nice copy-paste answer hehehe

Comment: @Selvin, that was taken from my code, It is possible that when I was new to android, I might have referred to the link you posted in comment.

Comment: it work great but i have to separe ecah world with the input ^x to assign a color ;)

Comment: you can check for ^ and parse accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use StringTokenizer class with delimiter "^" and then have to get first char from each word. This number can be an index in your color array for example List

EDIT:
Create stringTokenizer like this

```
StringTokenizer sT = new StringTokenizer(yourString, "^");

while(sT.hasMoreTokens()) {
String myColorString = sT.nextToken();
int color = myColorString.charAt(0);
String text = myColorString.substring(1, myColorString.length-1);
}
```

then you can get color by color variable and color your String text :).

When you will have number more than 2 chars you can use regular expression, but problem will appear when you want to have number on start of your String which you want to color :);

I think it will be better to make something like this 1;myString^2;myString2^3;myString3

and the you can use string tokenizer for each number;myString too.

Comment: i've looked on android doc but im not sure to realy understand :s can you explain little more please ?

Comment: can you remake an example please ? to be sure to undestand :p

Comment: yes please , with the input "^x" x=number who determine the color :)

Comment: x = color, y = string

x;y^x;y1^x1;y2

you have to use StringTokenizer with delimiters "^" and then with ";".

Comment: I have a little hard to understand well, could you post me a code with your example?

Comment: you have to get String and color index like in my answer and color them like in Gaurav Arora's answer

Comment: can y ou write a code please , I'm totally stuck on this function :(

Comment: I wrote you code I don't understand, you have to do it similary

Comment: Yes but i'd like to change my input with that : ^text1 if string start by ^ and end with number , ans how to show the result in a textview @Mathew1990

Answer (score -2):

write a function that receive the whole String and cut it in the seperate words (seperate by blanks) and give every word a color by a counter++.

Comment: can you give me a simple example please ?