# Can not get effect of SpannableString

Tags: android, string, spannablestring

I Want to add amount in String "confirm_msg"

```
    final int colorGreen = getResources().getColor(R.color.green_dark);
    SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString("$" +amount);
    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colorGreen), 0, ("$" +   amount).length(), 0);
    txtConfirmMSG.setText(getString(R.string.confirm_msg, spannable));
```

this is string in xml:

```
    <string name="confirm_msg">PLEASE CONFIRM THAT YOU WISH TO SEND A  %1$s </string>
```

Comment: We can not understand the desired effect. I would guess that you need to show "PLEASE CONFIRM THAT YOU WISH TO SEND A  XXXXXX" as spannable string, but it seems you are doing it wrong. Maybe you should call spannable.setText before txtConfirmMsg.setText?

Comment: i want  XXXXXX with R.color.green_dark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// try this way

<string name="confirm_msg">PLEASE CONFIRM THAT YOU WISH TO SEND A  %1$d$ </string>

 int amount = 150000;
        txtConfirmMSG.setText(setSpanColor(String.format(getString(R.string.confirm_msg),amount),String.valueOf(amount)));

 private SpannableStringBuilder setSpanColor(
            final String str,final String text) {
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

        if (str.contains(text)) {
            ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                }

                @Override
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                    ds.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_dark));
                }
            }, str.indexOf(text), str.indexOf(text)
                    + text.length(), 0);
        }
        return ssb;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use HTML to achieve different colors in `Spannable`.

You can check that answer: [Highlighting Text Color using Html.fromHtml() in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730706/highlighting-text-color-using-html-fromhtml-in-android)

Comment: no no no, its nit the best solution, first you have to build valid html (which can be sometimes difficult because of special characters like "<>" etc) Nd then Html.fromHtml has to parse it using Spanned and spans  anyway, so why not to do it directly?

Comment: so its elegant doing things twice? Html.fromHtml should in my opinion only be used when you already have html taken eg from external source. grep android source code for setSpan and fromHtml and you will see what they use