# How to change the ListView element text color based on text

Tags: android, listview

Displaying textview as list element, for this textview getting values by returning values from a method `getValues()`so setting text fot textview like this `t1.setText(getValues());`these values are like (123 kms,12 kms,13 kms,15 kms,198 kms,135 kms,456 kms,12 kms,135 kms,147 kms,....)i want to compare all elements with first one and if it is grater than first element that text color is RED ,if it it less than first element it is BLUE ,i tried something like this and got two lists.

**What i tried**

```
 List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(12,34,45,23,45,7,68,4,345,56,67,4,999,454,6,76,0);
        Iterator<Integer> iter = myList.iterator();
        List<Integer> lessList = new ArrayList<Integer>(), biggerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer firstItem = iter.next();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Integer currElement = iter.next();
            if (firstItem.compareTo(currElement) > -1) {
                lessList.add(currElement);
            } else {
                biggerList.add(currElement);
            }
        }
```

here i am not getting how to set text of textview and two colors for same textview. help me.

tried code something like this

```
 if(odo_chk_num>400)
                       {

                              if(t2!=null)
                              {
                                  t2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                t2.setText(getValues());
                              }

                       }  

 else
                       {
                           t2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                       }
```

but here first if condition executes then all texts color changing to RED,but what i need text should be RED based on condition only.
**ADAPTER CLASS**

```
public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Option>{

    private Context c;
    private int id;
    private List<Option>items;

    public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Option> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        c = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = objects;
    }
    public Option getItem(int i)
     {
         return items.get(i);
     }
     @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               View v = convertView;
               if (v == null) {
                   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   v = vi.inflate(id, null);
               }
               final Option o = items.get(position);
               if (o != null) {
                       TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                       TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

                       if(o.getDDS().equals("Odometer reading:"))
                       {

                           int odo_num, odo_chk_num = 0;
                           System.out.println("");
                           String odo_str=o.getSpans();

                           for(int i = 0 ; i<o.getSpans().length();i++)
                           {
                               char xyz=odo_str.charAt(i);
                               System.out.println("");
                               if(xyz >= '0' && xyz <= '9')
                               {
                               odo_num=(int)xyz;

                               odo_chk_num=  odo_chk_num*10 + odo_num;

                               }

                           }

                         //  System.out.println("after digit" + odo_chk_num);


                           if(odo_chk_num>40000)
                           {
                               if(t1!=null)
                                    t1.setText(o.getDDS());
                                  if(t2!=null)
                                  {
                                     // t2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                      SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(o.getSpans());
                                      ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 158, 158));
                                      sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 
                                    t2.setText(sb);
                                  }

                           } 

                       }


                       else
                       {
                           t2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                       if(t1!=null)
                        t1.setText(o.getDDS());
                       if(t2!=null)
                        t2.setText(o.getSpans());
                       }

               }
               return v;
       }

}
```

Comment: are you using a custom adapter to populate your list view/

Comment: Yes,i am using custom adapter ..

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150983/can-not-get-effect-of-spannablestring

Comment: Post your code for adapter.

Comment: use a spannable string in order to turn only a portion of the text red

Comment: i don't want to change the portion of text color

Answer (score 0):

Make one wrapper class take all varible in that class and one additional varible which is color code which is int type and calculate this condition in one method and fill all data and color code in wrapper after that you fill your list with this wrapper and your color code is also constant or not changing while you scroll you view.